# Facebook Comments Box mobile version not resizing

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, uiwebview, facebook-social-plugins

I am integrating a like button and a comment box (mobile) inside a web view in iOS (Using Facebook social plugins). I got it to work a few days ago but today, for some strange reason, it won't work correctly. When the user has not logged in, it looks almost fine:
[image]

But once I am logged in, and the UIWebView detects the Facebook cookie, it won't load correctly. The loading icon is misplaced, and it won't stop, no errors appear, no web is being loaded (checked with UIWebView delegate methods), the Comment button won't be loaded and the frame won't change its height to see more comments...

[image]

If I load this URL externally from Safari, iOS Safari will load the webpage correctly!
If I force loading the normal version (not the mobile one) the comments are loaded correctly!
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved...
It seems you have to force the login in https://m.facebook.com/login.php for some weird reason..... (not https://www.facebook.com)
They may have added this restriction now :\